# JS slideshow works one way

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

My slideshow is suffering from erratic behaviour. it's driven by pagers which the user clicks.  when the corresponding pager is clicked, the next image is made visible (opacity/filter) and set as z-index 5 so that it should sit beneath the present image (z-index 10).  The current image is then faded-out and finally, the next image is set to current and the image that has faded out is set to z-index 0. However, this only works when clicking back to a previous image (in Chrome, ie is behaving even more strangely.) in the order of images. That is to say,

- **chrome:**
- "list_slide1" to "list_slide3" instant jump with no fade
- "list_slide3" to "list_slide1" fade behaves correctly
- **then...**
- "list_slide1" to "list_slide3" instant jump no fade "list_slide3" to
- "list_slide2" fade behaves correctly
- **or...**
- "list_slide1" to "list_slide6" instant jump no fade
- "list_slide6" to any preceding list-slide1-5 fade behaves correctly
- **IE:**
- "list_slide1" to "list_slide3" instant jump with no fade
- "list_slide3" to "list_slide1" a second pause then jump

The pagers and the images are dynamically generated from a database (hence the little piece of PHP at the bottom of the code). it contains as many items as are listed for the page in the database.

a few notes:

> 1) the fade function is my own take on
>   http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation and has worked just fine in
>   another slideshow elsewhere on the site.
>
> 2) getElementsByClass is from http://www.robertnyman.com and returns
>   parent and child elements of the requested class in an array (hence
>   why I call current[0] etc.)

thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var pager = document.getElementById('pager1');
var list_pagers = document.getElementById('pagers')
var i = 0;

var next_slide = function(next) {  
  if (next.className !== 'slide_current') {

    if (getElementsByClassName('slide_pending').length === 0) {
      var current = getElementsByClassName('slide_current');
      next.className = 'slide_pending';
      next.style.zIndex = 5;
      next.style.opacity = 1;
      next.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 100)';
      next.style.display = 'block';
      fade(current[0], linear, 1000);
      var fadeSlide = switcher(next, current);   
    }
  }  
}

var switcher = function(now, then) {

  setTimeout(function() {
  now.className = 'slide_current';
  now.style.zIndex = 10;
  now.style.opacity = 1;
  now.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 100)';

  then[0].className = 'slide_hide';
  then[0].style.zIndex = 0;

  then[0].style.opacity = 0;
  then[0].style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 0)';
  then[0].style.display = 'none';
  }, 1001);
}

<?php
// dynamically build event for each pager/slide in the show.
for ($k = 1; $k <= $i; $k++) {
  echo  'var next_slide' .$k. ' = document.getElementById("list_slide" +' .$k. '); ',
        'addEvent(list_pagers.childNodes[' .($k - 1). '], "click", function () {next_slide(next_slide' .$k. ')}); ';
}
?>
```

Comment: adding 

fade(next, linear, 1000, 'in'); ('in' runs the animation for fading in rather than fading out).

helps the chrome version. Erratic behaviour still in IE. I think it's something to do with animating a <div> with multiple child elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

the problem was that the `<div>` tags i was trying to fade each contained an `<img>` and another `<div>`... the CSS being applied was either working inconsistently/erratically or - as is IE's wont - not-at-all.... The solution was - rather than animating the fade of the parent `<div>` - animating the respective child components separately. At first, it looked like the IE solution was completely unto itself; in fact, it was insightful to creating a neat, lightweight non-JQuery slideshow for all the browsers. One trade-off was that I had to incorporate all the styling into the element tags rather than a separate CSS. This seemed like the only viable option in this instance by virtue of the nature of the DOM requests being made...
Questions/feedback gratefully received:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var list_pagers = document.getElementById('pagers')
var i = 0;

<?php
// dynamically build event for each pager/slide in the show.
for ($k = 1; $k <= $i; $k++) {
  echo  'var next_slide' .$k. ' = document.getElementById("list_slide" +' .$k. '); ',
        'addEvent(list_pagers.childNodes[' .($k - 1). '], "click", function () {next_slide(next_slide' .$k. ')}); ';
}
?>

var next_slide = function(next) {  
  if (next.className !== 'slide_current') {
      if (navigator.appName === 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        //IE 7 & 8 
        if ((navigator.appVersion.search('MSIE 8.0') >= 1) || (navigator.appVersion.search('MSIE 7.0') >= 1)) {

          var current = getElementsByClassName('slide_current')[0].childNodes[0];
          var currentBar = getElementsByClassName('slide_current')[0].childNodes[1];
          var nextBar = next.childNodes[1]; 
          var nextSlide = next.childNodes[0];
        } else {
        //IE 9
          var current = getElementsByClassName('slide_current')[0].childNodes[1];
          var currentBar = getElementsByClassName('slide_current')[0].childNodes[2];
          var nextBar = next.childNodes[2]; 
          var nextSlide = next.childNodes[1];
        }

        // give the next slide and its header (nextBar) a temporary status of zIndex 5/6
        nextSlide.style.zIndex = 5;
        nextBar.style.zIndex = 6;
        nextSlide.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=100)";
        nextBar.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=85)";

        fade(currentBar, linear, 500); // fade currentBar out
        fade(current, linear, 500); // fade current out

        //once we've faded out current slides, it's time to replace them with th
        setTimeout(function() {
          getElementsByClassName('slide_current')[0].className = 'slide_hide';
          next.className = 'slide_current';
          nextSlide.style.opacity = 1; // IE 9 includes opacity...
          nextBar.style.opacity = 1; // IE 9 includes opacity...
          nextSlide.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=100)";  
          nextBar.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=85)";
          nextSlide.style.zIndex = 10;
          nextBar.style.zIndex = 11;
        }, 500);         

    } else {
      // NON IE TAGS    
      var current = getElementsByClassName('slide_current')[0];
      current.childNodes[1].style.zIndex = 10; // [1] the child <img> tag
      current.childNodes[2].style.zIndex = 11; // [2] the child <div> tag
      current.childNodes[1].style.opacity = 1;
      current.childNodes[2].style.opacity = 0.85;    
      next.childNodes[1].style.zIndex = 5;
      next.childNodes[2].style.zIndex = 6;
      next.childNodes[1].style.opacity = 1;
      next.childNodes[2].style.opacity = 0.85;      
      fade(current.childNodes[1], linear, 600); // fade current out
      fade(current.childNodes[2], linear, 600); // fade current out
      var fadeSlide = setTimeout(function() {switcher(next, current)}, 500); 
      var switcher = function(now, then, nowBar, thenBar) {

        then.className = 'slide_hide';
        then.childNodes[1].style.opacity = 0;
        then.childNodes[2].style.opacity = 0;
        now.className = 'slide_current';  
        now.childNodes[1].style.opacity = 1;
        now.childNodes[2].style.opacity = 0.85;
        now.style.opacity = 1;
      }
    }
  }  
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for not posting an answer to your exact problem, but I would steer away from writing Javascript plugins yourself for the following reasons:

- Hundreds of them exist on the Web already, some of which are developed on GitHub as open source, preventing potential issues through collaborative development.
- There is no need to reinvent the wheel; simply spend 20 minutes googling javascript sliders and find one that you can customise to your needs.

A couple I like using are 'caroufredsel', which is responsive and offers a few nice features (dynamically adding items, callbacks etc).

Another is 'flexslider'.

Comment: thanks, I will investigate, however it seems a shame to ditch the present arrangement when it nearly works so well.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with writing your own...How else will we ever learn, if we have to wait for something that has never been done before?

Comment: I'm glad I did, iGanja. I learnt a huge amount about what the DOM is/isn't capable of in the process and the result is a faster load. See my code below.